# Counting records in a SQL subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm having difficult with a subquery. In plain English I'm trying to pick a random userID from the QCUsers table that has less than 20 records from the QCTier1_Assignments table.  The problem is that my query below is only picking users where it meets the criteria of the inner query when I need it to pick any user from QCUsers table even if the user does not have any records at all in the QCTier1_Assignments table. I need something like this

AND (Sub.QCCount < 20 OR Sub.QCCount = 0 )

```
DECLARE @ReviewPeriodMonth varchar(10) = '10'
DECLARE @ReviewPeriodYear varchar(10) = '2015'

SELECT TOP 1
E1.UserID
,Sub.QCCount --Drawn from the subquery
FROM QCUsers E1
JOIN (SELECT 
  QCA.UserID, 
  COUNT(*) AS QCCount
  FROM QCTier1_Assignments QCA 
  WHERE QCA.ReviewPeriodMonth = @ReviewPeriodMonth
  AND QCA.ReviewPeriodYear = @ReviewPeriodYear
  GROUP BY QCA.UserID
  ) Sub
 ON E1.UserID = Sub.UserID
 WHERE Active = 1
  AND Grade = 12
  AND Sub.QCCount < 20
 ORDER BY NEWID()
```

I also tried it this way with no luck

```
DECLARE @ReviewPeriodMonth varchar(10) = '10'
DECLARE @ReviewPeriodYear varchar(10) = '2015'

SELECT TOP 1
E1.UserID
,Sub.QCCount --Drawn from the subquery
FROM QCUsers E1
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 
  QCA.UserID,
  ReviewPeriodMonth,
  ReviewPeriodYear, 
  COUNT(*) AS QCCount
  FROM QCTier1_Assignments QCA       
  GROUP BY 
    QCA.UserID,
    ReviewPeriodMonth,
    ReviewPeriodYear
  ) Sub
ON E1.UserID = Sub.UserID
WHERE Active = 1
  AND Grade = 12
  AND Sub.QCCount < 20
  AND Sub.ReviewPeriodMonth = @ReviewPeriodMonth
  AND Sub.ReviewPeriodYear = @ReviewPeriodYear
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using your second query but change the `WHERE` clause to use   `COALESCE(Sub.QCCount, 0) instead of just`Sub.QCCount`

If the subquery returns no rows then with your `RIGHT JOIN` you'll at least still get the row, but the QCCount will be `NULL` which when compared to anything will result in a "false" effectively.

Also, you should look into the `HAVING` clause. It might allow you to do this without a subquery at all.

Here's an example with the `HAVING` clause. If it doesn't give the correct results please let me know as I'm not able to test this.

```
DECLARE
    @ReviewPeriodMonth VARCHAR(10) = '10'
    @ReviewPeriodYear  VARCHAR(10) = '2015'

SELECT TOP 1
    E1.UserID,
    COUNT(QCA.UserID) AS QCCount
FROM
    QCUsers E1
LEFT OUTER JOIN QCTier1_Assignments QCA ON
    QCA.UserID = E1.UserID AND
    QCA.ReviewPeriodMonth = @ReviewPeriodMonth AND
    QCA.ReviewPeriodYear = @ReviewPeriodYear
WHERE
    E1.Active = 1 AND
    Grade = 12 AND
HAVING
    COUNT(*) < 20
ORDER BY
    NEWID()
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example of using HAVING here?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include an example with `HAVING`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN(INNER JOIN)`, And you'd better to put the predicate to the outer query based on your practice, but I recommend the following way:

```
SELECT TOP1 ABC.UserID,ABC.QCCount
FROM
(
    SELECT E1.UserID, COUNT(*) as QCCount
    FROM QCUsers as E1
    LEFT JOIN QCTier1_Assignments as QCA 
    ON QCA.UserID = E1.UserID
    WHERE QCA.ReviewPeriodMonth = @ReviewPeriodMonth
    AND QCA.ReviewPeriodYear = @ReviewPeriodYear
    AND Active = 1
    AND Grade = 12
    GROUP BY E1.UserID 
 ) as ABC
WHERE ABC.QCCount <20
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work it out through a combination of responses here

```
DECLARE @ReviewPeriodMonth varchar(10) = '10'
DECLARE @ReviewPeriodYear varchar(10) = '2015'

SELECT TOP 1 
  QCUsers.UserID, 
  COUNT(QCTier1_Assignments.ReviewID) AS ReviewCount
FROM         
QCTier1_Assignments RIGHT OUTER JOIN
QCUsers ON QCTier1_Assignments.UserID = QCUsers.UserID
WHERE     
QCUsers.Active = 1
AND QCUsers.Grade = '12'
AND (ReviewPeriodMonth = @ReviewPeriodMonth OR ReviewPeriodMonth IS NULL)
AND (ReviewPeriodYear = @ReviewPeriodYear OR ReviewPeriodYear IS NULL)
GROUP BY 
QCUsers.UserID
HAVING      
(COALESCE(COUNT(QCTier1_Assignments.ReviewID),0) < 4)
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: learn to reverse the tables (to avoid right joins), after counts have been performed they won't be null, so no need for coalesce in that having clause